# how to edit joomla plugin?

Tags: php, css, joomla2.5

I m new to joomla development. I downloaded joomla 2.5 and installed on my local computer for practice. My question is can we edit joomla plugin layout. I want to change default layout of Content - Pagebreak plugin(pagination that come when we add page break in article). I browse through joomla admin login but didn't find anything so How to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.myjoomlacast.com/joomla_1_5x/index.php/joomla-how-to-basics/joomla-extensions/the-plugin-manager/edit-a-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is possible 2 ways to edit the layout of joomla plugin.
**1.To go the administrator->plugin manager->select the plugin to edit.Here at the right side you will get some parameters like change the skin,count,height,width etc. depends on your plugin. by using this option you can choose the setting or layout whatever you want.most plugins have the skin drop down menu by which you can change the look of the plugin.**

**2.second is if you have knowledge of html & php than edit to the code directly.goto root file(ex.joomla2.5)->plugin->select the plugin file and edit it.**

Comment: Thanks for reply Harshal. I took 2nd option, changed by plugin and it works.